# How to fix package URI not found?

Tags: dart

The

```dart
'import: dart_application_1/dart_application_1.dart' as dart
```

in the bin file of my dart project has an error message. The error message reads,

```
"Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:dart_application_1/dart_application_1.dart'.Try creating a file referenced by the URI, or try using a URI for a file that does exist
```

Comment: just write it will ,  auto complete help you ,

Comment: Your project's `pubspec.yaml` file should declare its name to be `dart_application_1`.